# blog post code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to write a page where user's can write a blog post and publish it to the blog. I've downloaded blog engine .NET and looked at the code and I like the way they do it, but it's completely an overkill of what I need. What I need is only a title, author, date, and the blog post it self. I don't even want users to post comments or anything like that. My approach is to save all those blog post information into an xml and then when a page loads it loops around those xml files to show the blog post.

Is there a tutorial on how to do this online? Especially for doing blog posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a leaner out of the box option there is [Subtext](http://www.subtextproject.com/MainPage.ashx)

or if you want to start from scratch you could start with a code project sample blog engine: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/abe01.aspx

Creating a blog engine from scratch always leads to adding more features that come out of the box in most blog engine.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...are there any alternatives besides the one you posted? google doesn't really seems to help much